# Attachment is not open when i send a file attachment in php

Tags: php, forms, email, attachment, email-attachments

I used this code for sending an attachment from form to my email but i facing 2 problems :
1- sometime it's working and sometime stop working 
2-when i recive attachmet in my email i can see the attach file with size but it's not open and for word document file is open but it's empty same happen for picture and excel files and pdf any one can help?????

```
<?php
// Email address to which you want to send email
$to = 'xxx@xxx.com';
$subject = $_POST['fname'];
//$message = nl2br($_POST["fname"]);
/*********Creating Uniqid Session*******/
$txtSid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$headers = "";
$headers .= "From: ".$_POST['fname']."<".$_POST['femail'].">\r\nReply-To:   
".$_POST['femail']."\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$txtSid."\"\r\n\n";
$headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$txtSid."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\n";
//$headers .= $message."\r\n\n";
/***********Email Attachment************/
if($_FILES['attachment']['name'] != "")
{
    $txtFilesName = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
    $txtContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['attachment']  
['tmp_name']))); 
    $headers .= "--".$txtSid."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$txtFilesName."\"\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$txtFilesName."\"\r\n\n";
    $headers .= $txtContent."\r\n\n";
}

// @ is for skiping Errors //
$flgSend=@mail($to,$subject,null,$headers);  
if($flgSend)
{
    echo "Email Sent SuccessFully, WelServ will contact you as soon as possible.<br/>you 
will be redirected in 5 seconds<br/>";
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.setTimeout(function() 
{location.href='hire.php'}, 5000)</script>";

}
else
{
    $errorread=error_get_last(); 
    echo '$errorread';
    echo "Error in Sending Email, please try again,  you will be redirected in 5 
seconds!<br/>";
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.setTimeout(function() 
{location.href='hire.php'}, 5000)</script>";
}

?>
```

Comment: For the x-th time: Don’t do stuff like this yourself using PHP’s mail, but use a mailer class like PHPMailer or Swift Mailer instead.

Comment: and what about zend-mail i'm new to these mailer